# Trying to find a .NET GeoJSON library

Tags: .net, geojson

I'm trying to find a .NET [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id14) library which I can use to export my [SqlServer2008 spatial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx) boundaries (in binary format -> eg. `STAsBinary()`) from my .NET code to my HTML frontend to display on a google map.

At first I felt that it might be a StackOverflow question, but this site I feel is more specialised to helping me out.

Does anyone know of any?

NOTE: This dll does NOT have to be imported into SqlServer2008. In fact, it will not. I'll use it in my C# MVC WebSite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this article: [SQL Server 2008 + VirtualEarth made easier and building a REST API](http://viswaug.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/sql-server-2008-virtualearth-made-easier-and-building-a-rest-api/)

Answer (score 2):

The C# bindings for gdal/ogr are always an option.  You can create a geometry instance using WKB, and then export to JSON.

[http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRGeometry.html](https://gdal.org/api/ogrgeometry_cpp.html)

Comment: @user980 - can this WKB data .. which will be transported over the wire as JSON .. be loaded into google maps?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC, it is fairly easy to setup a few classes for FeatureCollection, Feature, and then your Geometry type then serialize them using JsonResult.  For Json arrays like "features" you can use an arraylist, and for a feature's "properties" use a dictionary with strings for keys and objects for values.

If not MVC, you can do something similar with Json.NET.

Hope that helps,
David

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GeoJSON.Net](https://github.com/jbattermann/GeoJSON.Net). I have no experience with it yet. But I'm planning to work with it. I'll let you know it's usefulness when I do.

Comment: Are you a bot? I've seen this answer across multiple questions? When are you going to get back and update everyone with it's usefulness?

Comment: I'm not a bot. And I didn't use it so I can't tell it's usefulness.

Comment: It's not a particularly useful answer then.

Comment: In looking at that library, it does not appear to have any facilities to read from WKT, WKB, or GML, which are the formats I have seen supported for exporting to from SqlGeography.